# Extract everything string before last bottom line

Tags: r, substring

I have a string like this:

```
"19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv"
```

I want to extract every string before last underscore:

```
"19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```

I have tried this:

```
gsub("_.//*", "", x)
```

But got the same

`"19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gsub("_\\w+$", "", x)
```

Comment: This will not work since `.` is not part of `\\w`. Also note that OP jus needs to delete the word `COUNTRY`

Answer (score 2):

Use `_[^_]*\\.`

- `_` starts with `_` (literal underscore character)
- `[^_]*` followed by everything but not `_` (`[^_]`) for any repetition (`*`)
- `\\.` followed by `.`. `.` needs to be escaped with `\\` otherwise `.` will match everything.

```
sub("_[^_]*\\.", ".", x)
#[1] "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```

Or with a non consuming look ahead.

```
sub("_[^_]*(?=\\.)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```

Data

```
x <- "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
x <- "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv"
gsub("_[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.", ".", x)
#[1] "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```

The pattern matches an underscore, followed by any (`*`) combinations of letters and numbers (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), followed by a dot (`\\.`), and replaces this by a dot.

Answer (score 1):

#### First Update:

```
string = "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv"
new_string = sub("_[^_]*$", ".csv", string)
```

Here, the `sub()` function can use the regular expression `_[^_]*$` to match and remove any group of characters after the last underscore `_`.

#### Second Update

As your question did not have the additional detail that you are providing through comments, I am updating my solution based on that.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(input_strings, "_[[:alnum:]]+\\.", ".")
```

The str_replace() function replaces the matched substring, consisting of an underscore followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by a period. The regular expression used here (`_[[:alnum:]]+\\.`) matches this pattern. The `.` at the end of the pattern matches the period before the file extension.

##### Example

```
library(stringr)

input_s <- c("19970101_AM23_popu_123_ZA1_Country.csv", 
             "19971_Ma3_popa_223_A1Z_Alpha.ppt", 
             "970101_Mt43_appu_333_2Z1_Beta.xls", 
             "70101_Ax21_eopu_444_AX1_Tesla.xlsx")

output_s <- str_replace(input_s, "_[[:alnum:]]+\\.", ".")

print(output_s)

"19970101_AM23_popu_123_ZA1.csv"
"19971_Ma3_popa_223_A1Z.ppt"
"970101_Mt43_appu_333_2Z1.xls"
"70101_Ax21_eopu_444_AX1.xlsx"
```

Comment: This deletes the extension of the file So not correct

Comment: Please try now, I had blank strings which I have now replaced with the file extension ```.csv```

Comment: what If the extension is not `.csv`?

Comment: You can replace the ```.csv``` string with any other pattern you want to maintain. Do you have all file names with the same extension or different extensions?

Comment: still not correct. the extension can be anything not necessarily `csv`.

Comment: How about now? I have modified the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A non regex approach can also be achieved via `strsplit`, i.e.

```
split_x <- strsplit(x, "_", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
result <- paste(head(split_x, -1), collapse = '_')
ext <- tail(strsplit(x, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]], 1)
paste0(result, ".", ext)

#[1] "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```

You can also make it a function and vectorize it:

```
remove_last_part <- function(x) {
  split_x <- strsplit(x, "_", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  result <- paste(head(split_x, -1), collapse = '_')
  ext <- tail(strsplit(x, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]], 1)
  final_result <- paste0(result, ".", ext)
  return(final_result)
}

# Vectorize the function
remove_last_part_vec <- Vectorize(remove_last_part)

input <- c("19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv", "19930303_AM25_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv")

output <- remove_last_part_vec(input)

#19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv 19930303_AM25_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv 
#  "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"       "19930303_AM25_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1_Country.csv"

gsub("(.+)_.+(\\.)", "\\1\\2", string)

# [1] "19970101_AM23_popu_223_AZ1.csv"
```